# How do I display specific rows from a SQL database using ID as argument

Tags: php, mysql

I have php generated table that displays data as follow;

```
ID  Name
1   xxxx
2   xxxx
```

I would like to be able to click on ID number and display information  associated with the ID on separate page

Ive got so far:

table.php

```
include("connection.php");


$con=mysql_select_db('fm', $con);

$query = "SELECT * FROM table ; 
$result = mysql_query($query);

echo "<table>
 <tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Location</th>
</tr>";


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

echo "<tr><td><a href='send.php?=" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['id'] . "</a></td><td>" . $row['location'] . "</td></tr>";  
}

echo "</table>"; 
mysql_close(); 
?>
```

info.php

```
include ("connection.php");

  $con=mysql_select_db('fm', $con);

  $id=$_GET['id']; 
  $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=". $id;
  $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

  echo "<table> 
     <tr>
     <th>ID</th>
     <th>Property</th>
     <th>Location</th>
     <tr>";

     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
         echo "<tr><td>" . $row['id'] . "</td><td>" . $row['property'] . "</td></td>" . $row['location'] . "</td></tr>";
     var_dump($row);                
 }
             echo "</table>";


  $result = mysql_query($sql);

mysql_close($con);
```

Any input will be appreciated

Comment: What happens when you test the code?

Comment: I only get table header

Comment: Check your table column names is it really `id` or is it `ID`. Is id stored as a number or as text?

Comment: I have checked everything... I cant get why is not working...

Comment: Don't use old mysql_* functions. They are deprecated and don't support few features of database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have got a mistake here :

```
echo "<tr><td><a href='info.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "</td><td>" . $row['location'] . "</td></tr>";
```

you need to end the `<a>` element like this:

```
echo "<tr><td><a href='info.php?id=".$row['id']."'>".$row['id']."</a></td><td>" . $row['location'] . "</td></tr>";
```

Also you should use IF statement in the info.php because if you access it like :

```
info.php // without ?id=
```

you will have undefined variable $id. And its vulberable to mysql injection when you dont process the variable before using it in select.

You got mistake here in info.php in this line:

```
$result = mysql_query($query, $con);
```

it should look like this :

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

You got it right in table.php.

Comment: So what does it return? How does it looks like now? Can you inspect table element and post here actual content of the table? Did you try to var_dump the $row?

Comment: all other fields display data apart form id, is blank... I havent tried ver_dump.. i must admit that i am PHP newbie and some things a complete alien to me...

Comment: Ok i updated my answer. I forgot the apostrophe after $row['id']." inside <a> tag
Try to copy it now and tell me if it works.

Comment: ok.. so when i click on id a new page is displayed with the correct link localhost/xxx/info.php?=1 but it doesnt display any information.. any thoughts on this.. thanks btw for helping me..

Comment: I edited my answer for you so you can try it again. Also try to put var_dump($row); inside while cycle in info.php. And if my answer helped you, you can check it as right answer :-)

Comment: var_dump returns NULL, do you know what could be the reason?

Comment: @Peter can you update your question with the code that is giving you null? Did you put var_dump($row); inside while cycle? It would help if we could see what the code looks like now.

Comment: i edited the code... also when i run this  code i get this error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

I would change the echo command like this

```
echo "<tr><td>{$row['id']}</td><td>{$row['property']}</td></td>{$row['location']}</td></tr>";
```

The double quotes will take care of the values of the variables.

Comment: Not sure what 'it highlights everything in red' relates to but you must  have made a mistake, overlooked a doublequote or something.

Comment: @RST in order to use array vars inside double quotes they need to be wrapped in brackets - ie. {$row['id']}